# How do I access a node object property, if it is an array?

Tags: 8

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
```

Having loaded a node object in Drupal 8, I know how to access a property, if it is a single value, and assign it to a variable, `$test` in the example below:

```
$test = $node->field_1->value;
```

However, if `$node->field_1` contains an array, how do I access it so that I can assign it to `$test`? So `$test` would equal something like:

```
array(0 => 'apples', 1 => 'oranges')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no real need to convert it to an array, as you can already access members of a `FieldItemList` as an array:

```
$first = $node->field_1[0]->value;
$next = $node->field_1[1]->value;
```

This:

```
$node->field_1->value;
```

Is just a shortcut to the first item in the collection anyway (see [`FieldItemList::__get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemList.php/function/FieldItemList%3A%3A__get/8)).

If you need the values in exactly the format you specified, `FieldItemList` is also iterable:

```
foreach ($node->field_1 as $delta => $item) {
  $an_array[$delta] = $item->value;
}
```

Comment: Great that worked. Out of interest, why do you use `$delta => $item`, rather than `$key => $value`? Just personal preference, or is this the correct language to use when dealing with objects, rather than arrays?

Comment: It just better represents what those vars are in this context than key+value. Makes the code a bit easier to read